How to set Pool Extension for staking function?
Now I am trying to test stake and claimReward function following existing sample codes.
StakingPool.sol
contract StakingPool is Context, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {
//rest codes
  function stake(uint256 _amount) external nonReentrant {
    IERC20(token).safeTransferFrom(_msgSender(), address(this), _amount);
    _setShare(_msgSender(), _amount, false);
  }
  function _setShare(
    address wallet,
    uint256 balanceUpdate,
    bool isRemoving
  ) internal {
    if (address(extension) != address(0)) {
      try extension.setShare(wallet, balanceUpdate, isRemoving) {} catch {}
    }
    if (isRemoving) {
      _removeShares(wallet, balanceUpdate);
      emit Unstake(wallet, balanceUpdate);
    } else {
      _addShares(wallet, balanceUpdate);
      emit Stake(wallet, balanceUpdate);
    }
  }
  function setPoolExtension(IPoolExtension _extension) external onlyOwner {
    extension = _extension;
  }
  //rest codes
}

TokenStakingPool.sol
contract TokenStakingPool is IPoolExtension, ITokenStakingPool, Ownable {
  //rest codes
  function setShare(
    address wallet,
    uint256 balanceChange,
    bool isRemoving) external override onlyPool {
    if (isRemoving) {
      _withdraw(wallet, balanceChange);
    } else {
      _deposit(wallet, balanceChange);
    }
  }
  //rest codes
}

IPoolExtension.sol
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

interface IPoolExtension {
  function setShare(
    address wallet,
    uint256 balanceChange,
    bool isRemoving
  ) external;
}

In my opinion, for testing the staking function, before testing it, we have to run the setPoolExtension function first.
But I didn't know how to set the extension for the testing.
Please provide some advice for solving this problem.
Thanks

If you're asking if you have to initialize extension by calling setPoolExtension() then yes you do. Otherwise if you don't, extension will be its default value, address(0).
To do that you can either declare that in the constructor, or by calling the function setPoolExtension using the owner address.
The best is to do that at deployment using a deployment framework such as Hardhat, Foundry or Remix.
If you are learning and want to check and test out quickly concepts and ideas, Remix might the best for you.
ps: The full code is not displayed, and this is only my opinion, but the code i see doesn't seem to be of the best quality in terms of efficiency,simplicity, security and architectural choices.
